# join if string contains substring and return the rest as new row in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hi I would like to join table by substring in string and return not join as new row. Is that possible? Here's an example

| ID | price |
| --- | --- |
| 07a | 50 |
| 1b7 | 60 |
| 7TC | 40 |

| productCode | details |
| --- | --- |
| newhair_07a | detailA |
| black_1b7_chair | detailB |
| blueBed | detailC |

into a table where it matches the ID from table ID with the product table's productCode. If substring is in string then join the tables together and return no match into a new row.

Output will be like so

| ID | productCode | details | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07a | newhair_07a | detailA | 50 |
| 1b7 | black_1b7_chair | detailB | 60 |
|  | blueBed | detailC |  |
| 7TC |  |  | 40 |

I don't know where to begin to join this. Please do help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
with temp as (
  select id, productCode, details, price 
  from tableID
  join tableProduct
  on regexp_contains(productCode, id)
)
select * from temp 
union all
select id, null, null, price 
from tableID where not id in (select id from temp)
union all
select null, productCode, details, null  
from tableProduct where not productCode in (select productCode from temp)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a **FULL OUTER JOIN** problem. Assuming that your **productCode** is a *underbar separated value* which includes **ID**, below approach would be possible:

```sql
WITH joined AS (
  SELECT * EXCEPT (code)
    FROM tableB b JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(productCode, '_')) code 
    FULL JOIN tableA a ON a.ID = code
)
SELECT * FROM joined WHERE productCode IS NULL
 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM joined WHERE productCode IS NOT NULL
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY productCode, details ORDER BY ID NULLS LAST) = 1;
```

output:

[image]

sample tables:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE tableA AS (
  SELECT '07a' ID, 50 price
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '1b7', 60
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '7TC', 40
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE tableB AS (
  SELECT 'newhair_07a' productCode, 'detailA' details
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'black_1b7_chair', 'detailB'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'blueBed', 'detailC'
);
```